# Discrete Mathematics and Combinatorics, Combinatorial proof via counting dots

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

By counting a set of dots in two different ways, give a combinatorial proof that

$$n^2 = 2{n \choose 2} + n$$

I read an example online saying that $n^2$ can be represented by a square set of dots, and ${n \choose 2}$ can be represented by a triangle with $n$ rows and $n-1$ columns. When you put two of these triangles together you get a rectangle that is given by $n \times n-1$ in dimensions and the final $+n$ makes up for the missing column making the two sides equal.

I was wondering if there was a better way to write this proof out or if this is a solid proof for the question.

Comment: That feels to me more like a geometric proof rather than a double-counting proof.  It is correct, though it may help to remind the reader *why* $\binom{n}{2}$ represents the number of dots in the triangle you describe.  The type of double-counting I might have expected would instead have been in counting the number of ordered pairs in $[n]\times[n]$ in two ways.  The first way being the direct method, being done in $n^2$ ways.  The second way by breaking into cases: the two numbers are different and in increasing order, different in decreasing order, or the same, in $2\binom{n}{2}+n$ ways.

Comment: Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762334/504810 (another identity involving $n^2$ obtained by double-counting the same set)